# Python: get the index of two list where the values are the same

Tags: python, list, intersection

I have two lists of the same size containing values. I want to create a third list containing the index where the values are the same.

On StackOverflow I found this code :

```
def return_indices_correlated_guess(a, b):
  b_set = set(b)
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in b_set]
```

But for a reason it just returns me a list containing values from 0 to the size of the lists.

Here is list a:

```
[1, 1, 1, None, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, None, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Here is list b:

```
 [1, 0, 1, 1, None, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here is the list returned by `return_indices_correlated_guess(a,b)`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46]
```

The result should be a list containing `[0,2,...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted saves the indices of the first list **a** where any element in the list **b** is present.

To get list of indices where the values match,

1. compare element at the same index in both lists
2. if elements are equal save the index to output array.

**Code:**

```
def return_indices_correlated_guess(a, b):
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == b[i]]

a=[1, 1, 1, None, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, None, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

b= [1, 0, 1, 1, None, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

print(return_indices_correlated_guess(a,b))

# or simply 
print([i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == b[i]])
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 19, 23, 26, 28, 38, 46]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the function that you provides are returning the indexes of the values that are in the other list, but not in the same index.

Here you have an example solution to your problem:

```
def return_indices_correlated_guess(a, b):
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == b[i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing `zip` in the ring:

```
def return_indices_correlated_guess(a, b):
    return [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if x == y]
```

Note that this will work even if the lists have different lengthes.